# Is there a way to parameterize a pytest with multiple data types in a same test?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

Currently I have this implementation where I am running a parameterized pytest in this way:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('int_val', [1, 0])
   def test_int_val(self, int_val: int):
   # performs all the steps
```

and running the same test with boolean values this way:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('bool_val', [True, False])
    def test_bool_val(self, bool_val: int):
    # performs all the steps
```

Is there a way to combine both the tests in 1 test?

Comment: If you use the same code, you can just combine both - are the tests identical? And it would probably be `val: Union[int, bool]` for the type checker...

Comment: You didn't mention what you are doing with the values, but Python treats `1` and `0` as `True` and `False` (any number except for `0` will be considered `True`). You need to give more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen these tests are going to be identical. I am trying to run a custom command with these 4 values and checking the output. so it needs to be checked with int values - 1, 0 and then bool values true, false

Comment: So, in this case again, why not just put them together, e.g. `@pytest.mark.parametrize('val', [True, False, 1, 0])`?

Comment: ^^ Just treat all values as inputs and handle them accordingly in the test function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the below:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('bool_val', [True, False, 1, 0])
def test_bool(bool_val):
    print(f"VAL: {bool_val}")
    # your code
```

prints this:

```
tests/tests_temp.py::test_bool[True] VAL: True
PASSED
tests/tests_temp.py::test_bool[False] VAL: False
PASSED
tests/tests_temp.py::test_bool[1] VAL: 1
PASSED
tests/tests_temp.py::test_bool[0] VAL: 0
PASSED
```

Edit: as per OP's comment

Comment: but I want the test to run it with True first, check the results then false and check the results, then with 1 and check the results and then 0 and check the resutls

Comment: @conscious_breather edited

Comment: later in the test I am checking if bool_val is a boolean  then perform these steps and if it's a int perform these steps, in that case would 0 and 1 be treated as int or bool?

Comment: It will be treated as the same type that is passed. Also, any truthy value can be evaluated as true/false by doing `bool(val)`. You can check the type of the value passes using `isinstance`.